initial root password doesn't work for gitlab
I try to do a gitlab cluster with the official gitlab's helm repository for a school project.
I use the official documentation to create my gitlab cluster. https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/deployment.html
Here are my CLI commands I do to reproduce my problem:
sudo k3d cluster create gitlab
sudo kubectl create namespace gitlab
sudo helm repo add gitlab https://charts.gitlab.io/
sudo helm repo update
sudo helm upgrade --install gitlab gitlab/gitlab --timeout 600s --set global.hosts.domain=example.com --set global.hosts.externalIP=10.10.10.10 --set certmanager-issuer.email=me@example.com -n gitlab
When all is deployed:
With k9s (k9s is a terminal tool to easily manage the cluster) I port forward the service "gitlab-webservice-default".
Following the official documentation I write this to recover the initial root password :
sudo kubectl get secret gitlab-gitlab-initial-root-password -n gitlab -ojsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 --decode ; echo
On the website localhost:8181 (working thanks of the port forwarding)
I enter as username : root
as password : the password I recovered previously
Then I got a 422 error page :
"422: The change you requested was rejected Make sure you have access to the thing you tried to change.
Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is a mistake."
I don't know what I did wrong, any help would be appreciated :)

My guess is that port-forwarding the webservice allows me to connect to gitlab without using TLS, and gitlab may refuse my connection for this reason.
I retried to install gitlab with this updated values in the helm chart:
global:
  hosts:
    domain: localhost
    https: false
  ingress:
    configureCertmanager: false
    class: nginx
certmanager:
  install: false
gitlab-runner:
  install: false

Then it worked.
As I am studying, this configuration is ok for me.
